# Setting default make options for Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt4.7

How can i override default make parameters , which is:

`make -w`

Each time i create a project , i had to modify project settings , adding `-j4` to make parameters.

Can i set `make -w -j4` by default ?

### EDIT

The best way to do this is setting MAKEFLAGS environment variable , i'm picking the only answer as the best only to shut this thread down.

To set this for UNIX,  modify the *.desktop file of Qt Creator , prefix the line entitled `Exec=` with `env MAKEFLAGS=-j4` , but be aware that you won't be able to cease building in QtCreator immediately after setting to multithread.

Comment: Hint: you can simply write `-j`, it chooses the number of threads automatically, which you typically want (maybe not always).

Comment: @leemes this is often dangerous, for with complex cmake-generated projects this turns into a fork bomb and crashes my PC.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the qtcreator go to the "Projects tab" and set "Make arguments" as you like:
[image]

Comment: And also for further reference: [Qt Creator Build Setup](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-build-settings.html)

Comment: As per the question EDIT, this should not be the correct answer.

Comment: This is the best answer, but that field isn't there on recent versions (e.g. v4.7).

Comment: @user2023370 I disagree. In v4.7.0 and v4.7.1 it is there, once I click the `Details` button.

Comment: is it possible to put this setting in the `.pro` file of `MyQtApp` somehow?

Answer (score 26):

To make it global and permanent go to

```
Tools > Options > Build & Run > Kits > (pick your toolchain)
```

and fill your predefined env settings: `MAKEFLAGS=-j4`

[image: Screenshot what to click exactly]

Comment: This is now at:
Tools > Options > Kits > (pick your toolchain) > Environment

Answer (score 12):

If you want `-jx` parameter to be default each time you create a new or open some project, you must add enviroment variable `MAKEFLAGS` to your system with value `-jx`.

For example, at ubuntu for 8 - threding compilation this options can be realized by adding

> MAKEFLAGS="-j8"

to */etc/enviroments*

Result will be:
[image]

Comment: Hint: you can simply write `-j`, it chooses the number of threads automatically, which you typically want (maybe not always).

Comment: I tried "-j". It doesn't work. It says: "no process count specified for option -j"

Answer (score 2):

After attempting implement the fix described in the question I eventually found the following (clearly this in only a solution to linux's that use the freedesktop concept of .desktop files):

The line in "/usr/local/share/applications/Nokia-QtCreator.desktop" was:

```
Exec=/opt/qtcreator-2.5.2/bin/qtcreator.sh %F
```

I changed it to:

```
Exec=env MAKEFLAGS=-j16 /opt/qtcreator-2.5.2/bin/qtcreator.sh %F
```

And got the functionality requested in the question.

Ok, I have no idea why following the instructions in the question I didn't get there but I didn't. I hope this explanation will help someone.

Comment: Hint: you can simply write `-j`, it chooses the number of threads automatically, which you typically want (maybe not always).

Comment: I find that -j selects a number slightly too low for optimal compile speed. -j is close enough, but I like as fast as possible.