# MAKEFLAGS in Qt Creator via .pro project file

Tags: qt, c++11, qt4, qt5, qmake

The PC I'm using has 4 cores so I wanna use all them while compiling, which I do by passing the `-j4` option to the compiler. In Qt Creator I do that by adding an environment variable in the `Build Environment` panel, as shown in the images:

```
MAKEFLAGS = -j4
```

[image]

[image]

The problem is that this setting doesn't persist across all projects in the PC I'm using, which will be cool. So I have to do that for each project at least once. I think this is stored in the `.pro.user` file, since every time `.pro.user` gets deleted the `MAKEFLAGS = -j4` desapears from the `Build Environment` panel.

Isn't possible to just add this setting via `.pro` project file?

I'm interested in any approach which will allow me to escape from the necessity of setting that stuff multiple times.

To give a little context, I'm on Windows.

Comment: Just set the `MAKEFLAGS` environment variable to `-j4` see [setting default make options for qt creator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860712/setting-default-make-options-for-qt-creator)

Comment: The accepted answer there relies on `.pro.user`, so it will not persist forever.

Comment: Yes, but the author of the question could not "unaccept" the answer, so he edited his question to recommend setting the `MAKEFLAGS` environment variable... However, if  you want a persistent version of `.pro.user` you could use `.qmake.conf` instead.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about `.qmake.conf`. Even so it's not clear to me how it'll help in answering the question, perhaps someone could.

Comment: This is an X-Y problem question: You shouldn't presume that a particular solution (e.g. modifying MAKEFLAGS) is the answer. Instead, you should ask a more general question of how to share a particular project settings across projects you open. Had you googled that, you'd have found the answer yourself, too :)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [shared project settings](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-sharing-project-settings.html) in a `.pro.shared` file. They are designed exactly for what you have in mind.

Adding the setting to a `.pro` file is wrong, since that file is meant to be portable and not tied to any particular build host.